# Python file after sudden crash empty

Tags: python, crash, python-idle

I know this might not be a python question but it is an emergency, I had at least 3,000 lines of code and right when I was saved my file my laptop crashed. And I worked on this file everyday, so I saved it everyday. When I turned my computer on and opened that file I was working in, it was completely blank and empty. There was no code, but the file size was the same. Please, I am in a desperate need to recover my file, is there any way I can get it back?

Comment: It looks like you just learned [the second commandment of source control](https://dzone.com/articles/10-commandments-good-source) the hard way. Recovering data from a crashed machine isn't really a programming question at all.

Comment: Yes, need use an tool or open_whole_disk_binary_mode(most awe-full tings). Already maybe you deleted this file source if made an `reboot`.

Comment: What do you mean the file size was the same? Have you tried opening it in various editors? Are you sure it's the same file? Windows sometimes saves versions of a file. This is off topic and will be closed. Check [su].

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it before , but if you still have the .pyc file, you might get your code back from the bytecode file with this:

https://github.com/Mysterie/uncompyle2

For every file.py of python code, python creates a file.pyc where it precomiles your code into bytecode. Hope it helps. Good Luck!